# Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status) - Passing it to a switch statement

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I'm pretty new to MVC, but I have the following code:

```
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)
        @switch (item.Status)
        {
            case 0: Html.DisplayText("Requested");
                break;
            case 1: Html.DisplayText("In Progress");
                break;
            case 2: Html.DisplayText("Declined");
                break;
            default:
                Html.DisplayText("Undefined");
                break;
        }
    </td>
```

It renders the "Html.DisplayFor" fine, this is an integer. But really I want to display the equivalent text based on the item.Status in that same position. But this is not working. I could change the way the original class handles the status in the Get and Set methods but how would I do it this way?

Comment: Probably shouldn't be doing logic like that in a view. That's probably data that should be manipulated somewhere else and placed into the model as it's own property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a property on your ViewModel that does this logic for you.  Such as

```
public string StatusDescription { 
    get { 
        switch (this.Status) {
            case 0: 
                return "Requested";
            case 1:
                return "In Progress";
            // yada yada yada
        }
    }
}
```

And in your view, replace the switch statement with

```
Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StatusDescription);
```

Comment: Thank you all! I'm doing it this way now!

Answer (score 2):

I would create a declarative helper method (http://weblogs.asp.net/mikaelsoderstrom/archive/2010/10/06/declarative-helpers-in-razor.aspx) that displays the text based on the status. 
You can then call it similar to this in your view:

```
@Html.MyHelper(status)
```

Or even better, like the commenter on the original post said, you could create a property on your ViewModel that does this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expose that as a `StatusText` property on the model.

That kind of logic should really be separate from your UI.