# Is it possible to convert a boolean to a string in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column called `live_in_city` that provides a boolean value. I want to convert it to a string though.

I tried using `cast((live_in_city) as varchar(256))`, but it says cannot cast type boolean to character varying.

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Its postgressql.

Comment: The first answer on the following page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682381/html-displayformodelitem-item-status-passing-it-to-a-switch-statement/6682609#6682609

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using below. Here you can assign value to 1 and 0 . then convert that.

```
Select 
    Cast(Case 
            When live_in_city=1 Then 'True' 
            ELse 'False' END 
        AS Varchar(256))
    from #t
```

The above works if `live_in_city` is a number (integer, numeric, ...).

For a real `boolean` column, the following should be used:

```
Select Case 
         When live_in_city Then 'True' 
         ELse 'False' 
       END 
from the_table;
```

Comment: Do you really need the CAST() in this statement? You're already "manually casting" the results using the CASE.

Answer (score 13):

Casting to `TEXT` works fine for me in Postgres 9.5:

```
# select (0 = 0)::TEXT, (0 = 1)::TEXT;
 text | text  
------+-------
 true | false
(1 row)
```

and also your code works as well:

```
# SELECT cast((1 = 1) as varchar(256)), cast((1 = 0) as varchar(256));
 varchar | varchar 
---------+---------
 true    | false
(1 row)
```

Note: `(1 = 1)` and `(1 = 0)` are placeholders for all possible expressions, that returning `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 5):

You can cast it to text like this:

```
CAST(table.column AS TEXT)
```

Comment: This doesn't work in redshift FYI